Desactivar Distinct Automático en Select SQl Server
Tengo una tabla que a alguien se le hizo buena idea duplicar campos para un segundo producto, el problema es que ahora necesito tratar el segundo producto como un registro aparte, es decir, de:
select Id,Producto1,Cantidad1,Producto2,Cantidad2 from Datos 

Requiero:
select id,Producto1 as Prod, Cantidad1 as Cantidad from Datos
union
select id,Producto2 as Prod, Cantidad2 as Cantidad from Datos where cantidad2>0

el problema es que al hacer la consulta parece agruparme los valores como si hiciera un select distinct, es decir, si en el primer select tengo 10 registros y en el segundo 7, la consulta con el unión solo me muestra 10 en lugar de 17, quiero pensar que es por el campo ID que es Unique, pero incluso aun quitandolo del select hace lo mismo, como puedo hacer para que me muestre los 17 registros?

En vez de hacer uso de union utiliza union all el cual no elimina duplicados:
select id,Producto1 as Prod, Cantidad1 as Cantidad 
from Datos
union all
select id, Producto2 as Prod, Cantidad2 as Cantidad 
from Datos 
where cantidad2 > 0


Una mejor opción para evitar leer la tabla 2 veces es convertir las columnas en filas. Mi preferencia es usar la instrucción APPLY por la flexibilidad que ofrece. En este caso, genero SELECTs sin FROM unidos por UNION ALL que hacen referencia a la tabla Datos. De esta forma se duplican las filas y se generan columnas adicionales que puedes utilizar en el resultado que regresas.
SELECT  d.Id,
        u.Producto,
        u.Cantidad
FROM Datos d
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT d.Producto1, d.Cantidad1 
              UNION ALL
              SELECT d.Producto2, d.Cantidad2 WHERE d.Cantidad2 > 0)u(Producto, Cantidad)


interesante, haré la prueba, gracias!!
